# how to set a Color to an JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, background-color

the pink color don't work!

```
//Frame

JFrame f = new JFrame("Tab");

f.setBounds(100, 100, 1000, 1000);

f.setVisible(true);

f.setLayout(null);

f.setBackground(Color.pink);
```

Comment: pink and any other color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the content panel instead. Just substitute

```
f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.pink);
```

instead of

```
f.setBackground(Color.pink);
```